# Debugging this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, nullreferenceexception

I randomly get this error and would like to know the best way to debug this and what it means.

```
MESSAGE: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
SOURCE: POL
FORM: __VIEWSTATE={{LONG STRING OF TEXT HERE}}
URL: /SourceIt.aspx
QUERYSTRING:
TARGETSITE: Void Page_Load(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
STACKTRACE: at POL.PreDischargeEducation.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

EDIT:
This error also randomly happened. Could updating .NET or something server side have been the cause of this?

EDIT:

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            ctlBriefingAffidavitSpouse.Filer = "J";
            ErrorTR.Visible = false;
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = false;
            ErrorTRBottom.Visible = false;
            lblErrorMessageBottom.Visible = false;
            if (!IsPostBack) {
                CheckCheckmarks();
                ctlBriefingOverview.Visible = true;
            } else {
                string ctrlname = Request.Params.Get( "__EVENTTARGET" );
                if(ctrlname.Length <= 0)
                    ShowNextControl();
            }
        }
```

EDIT: This code is also not mine. I'm trying to debug why it randomly broke. I've noticed it seems to be an issue with IE 99% of the time when doing this specific action.

Comment: you will have to post corrosponding code to figure out

Comment: Are you using ASP **Classic**, or **ASP.NET** ? You have tags for both - which cannot be - it's either classic or ASP.NET .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason could be you are using `Session` variable or some other variable without checking it to null.
The error is suggesting that you have error on `SourceIt.aspx` `page_load` and error type is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

What you can do is checking for `null` before using your `Session` variables.

Like if you are using say `Session["UserId"].ToString()` then you should check it for null first as below

```
 if(Session["UserId"]!=null)
    //wirte your code here.
```